# JS: getting error line number inside `new Function(...)`

Tags: javascript, function, error-handling

In my application I parse some user input and then run it as Javascipt code using `(new Function(...))()`. If the input is incorrect, this throws an exception. What I need is a way to get the line number where the exception happened in the parsed string that had been provided to `new Function()`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this we need to write a logic to capture the stacktrace from the error object and find out where exactly the `anonymous` function has indicated the error has been thrown.

The line number where the error is thrown in Chrome is indicated as `<anonymous>:5:17`, where as in Firefox it is `Function:5:17`

```js
try{
 (new Function(`var hello = 10;
                const world = 20;
                let foo = 'bar';
                xyz; //simulating error here
 `))();
}catch(err){
   let line = err.stack.split("\n").find(e => e.includes("<anonymous>:") || e.includes("Function:"));
   let lineIndex = (line.includes("<anonymous>:") && line.indexOf("<anonymous>:") + "<anonymous>:".length) ||  (line.includes("Function:") && line.indexOf("Function:") + "Function:".length);
   console.log(+line.substring(lineIndex, lineIndex + 1) - 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
formatError(err)
{
    const regex = new RegExp("<anonymous>:[0-9]*:[0-9]*");
    const anynomError = err.stack.match(regex);

    if (anynomError.length > 0)
    {
        const lineNumber = anynomError[0].split(":")[1] - 2;
        return `Error on line ${lineNumber}: ${err}`;
    }

    return err;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).